# Плохо компилируется код в vscode

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, visual-studio-code

Я бы хотел, чтобы после компиляции кода строка в терминале автоматически переносилась на следующую строчку. Я компилирую код в vscode с расширением С/С++ Compile Run. После компиляции строка терминала остается на строчке с результатом компиляции, что очень сильно мне не нравится. После кода вставлять `cout << '\n';` тоже не вариант. Помогите пожалуйста, может в JSON что-либо прописать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: *вставлять cout << '\n'; тоже не вариант* - а почему?..

Comment: Код не "плохо компилируется", а делает именно то что вы написали, и не более того. Если вы не делаете в конце перенос строки, то он сам и не добавится.

Comment: В принципе, можно добавить перенос строки в сообщение шелла, но тогда оно всегда будет выводиться. То есть на скриншоте перевод строки добавился бы трижды.

Answer (score 2):

Увы, но за форматирование вывода вашей программы отвечаете персонально вы. Если вы хотите, чтобы у пользователя в терминале переводилась строка - вам нужно это сделать в своем коде - написать `cout << endl;`

`endl` в данном случае важен, так как он не только переводит строку, но и сбрасывает буфер.

Comment: Эх, ну ладно. Спасибо